# Converting image to black and white and use it as array

Tags: python, image, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to convert a colored image to a black and white one.

The original image is the following:

[image]

I have a few problems. First:

```
import pylab as pl
import Image

im = Image.open('joconde.png')

pl.imshow(im)
pl.axis('off')
pl.show()
```

I get this:

[image: First result]

Why is it rotated? That's not the point but I'd like to know why.

```
im_gray = im.convert('1')

pl.imshow(im_gray)
pl.show()
```

And here is the processed black and white image:

[image]

Now everything looks working. But I need to use that image as a numpy array in order to do some image processing. All I have to do is this:

```
import numpy as np

im_arr = np.array(im_gray)

pl.imshow(im_arr)
pl.axis('off')
pl.show()
```

But I get this:

[image]

Why is this happening? I tried also:

```
im_arr = np.array(im_gray, dtype='float')
```

or:

```
im_arr = np.asarray(im_gray)
```

But nothing seems working. Maybe the problem is in the `show` method but I don't know.

Comment: You image is not rotated, it is flipped vertically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your image is rotated because of an origin problem.

If you use this snippet, the image will not be rotated upside-down.

```
pl.imshow(im, origin='lower')
pl.show()
```

You could also simply use `im.show()` to display the image.

Now, back to the original question. I think the problem comes from the fact that pylab cannot handle bilevel images. You certainly want to use a greyscale image and thus do this

```
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np
import Image

im = Image.open('your/image/path')
im_grey = im.convert('L') # convert the image to *greyscale*
im_array = np.array(im_grey)
pl.imshow(im_array, cmap=cm.Greys_r)
pl.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the way you convert the image into numpy array. If you look at what the outputs from the functions are this becomes clear

```
>> np.array(im_gray)
array([[False, False, False, ...,  True, False, False],
   [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True, False],
   [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True, False],
   ..., 
   [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
   [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
   [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

That can't be right. `pl.imshow` takes an array of `floats` `uint8` or `PIL` image, not an array of booleans. So you need to do the conversion into an array more explicitly, making sure to

```
cols,rows = im_gray.size
pixels = list(im_gray.getdata())

# an indexer into the flat list of pixels
# head ranges from 0 to len(pixels) with step cols
# tail ranges from cols to len(pixels) with step cols
head_tail = zip(range(0,len(pixels)+1,cols),range(cols,len(pixels)+1,cols))
im_data = np.ndarray(shape=(cols,rows), dtype=np.uint8)

# extract each row of pixels and save it to the numpy array
for i,(head,tail) in enumerate(head_tail):
    im_data[i] = np.array(pixels[head:tail], dtype=np.uint8)

pl.imshow(im_data, cmap='bone')
```

The final `pl.imshow` requires you to define a colormap. The `'bone'` colormap is black and white. I presume passing a `PIL` image into the functions defines the colormap automagically.